# Find the basis for the eigenspace. Can it be the zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I am trying to obtain a basis for an eigenspace given the standard matrix of a linear operator over a space. I have done all of the work. I just need to confirm my results or find my mistake.

A=[F]=
   \begin{array}{ccc}
   3 & 2 & 1 \\
   0 & 2 & 4 \\
   0 & 0 & 4
  \end{array}

After finding $|\lambda I - A|$ I get that the eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1}=2$, $\lambda_{2}=3$ and $\lambda_{3}=4$. I am having a problem with $\lambda=4$. When I compute $4I-A$, the computation yields that there is no basis for the nullspace, does this mean that there is no basis for this eigenspace?

4I-A=
  \begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & -2 & -1 \\
   0 & 2 & -4 \\
   0 & 0 & -4
  \end{array}

So then upon row reducing to the canonical form $C$, I obtain the identity matrix.

I_3=
  \begin{array}{ccc}
   1 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
  \end{array}

This says that $x=y=z=0$.

So, is this the basis for the eigenspace? The basis for the nullspace does not exist since the only vector in the basis of the nullspace is the zero vector.

Comment: Did you imagine the possibility of having made a computational error? The matrix of $4I-A$ has a final row all zero, so its kernel is effectively given by a (homogeneous) system of only two equations (the other two rows) in three unknowns. Such a system should always have nonzero solutions. In fact it seems you computed (in the final entry) $4-4=-4$; that's not quite exact.

Answer (score 2):

No. A basis is a linearly *in*-dependent set. And the set consisting of the zero vector is *de*-pendent, since there is a nontrivial solution to $c\vec{0}=\vec{0}$.

If a space only contains the zero vector, *the empty set* is a basis for it. This is consistent with interpreting an empty sum as zero.

---

But with respect to your computation, you are just not computing $4I-A$ correctly. Look again at the lower right entry.

Comment: Thank you. So there is no distinction between basis of an eigenspace and the basis of said eigenspace's nullspace?

Comment: What is an "eigenspace's nullspace"? A matrix can have a nullspace. A linear transformation can have a nullspace. But an eigenspace does not have a nullspace. A nullspace is just a particular type of eigenspace, where $0$ is the associated eigenvalue.

Comment: Oh wow. Okay. That clears that up quite a bit. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Since nobody seems to have computed it correctly yet, let me just say that the nullspace of $4I-A$ is generated by the vector $v=(5,2,1)$; indeed $Av=(20,8,4)=4v$.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I found that to be correct when I did the computation. Thanks for posting for future viewers of this problem. I probably should have done that!

Comment: Thanks for computing this properly

Answer (score 1):

It is a theorem that $\det(B) = 0 \iff B$ is singular.  So the very fact that an eigenvalue exists implies that the matrix $A-\lambda I$ is singular: we have found a $\lambda$ such that $\det(A-\lambda I) = 0$.

Therefore, in this case, $\operatorname{Rank}(A-4I) < 3$, and so $A - 4I$ must have at least one row of zeros in its reduced row echelon form.  Note that this also implies a nontrivial nullspace:  The rank-nullity theorem tells us that $\operatorname{Rank}(B) + \dim( \operatorname{Null(B)}) = n$ for any $n \times n$ matrix $B$.

In other words, the eigenspace for a given eigenvalue *must* have at least one nontrivial basis vector.

Long story short, you've made an error (highlighted by Omnnomnomnom in his answer).

Comment: I understand. Because the reduced row echelon form has only two non-zero rows (rank), their exists a basis for the nullspace containing only one non-trivial vector. Is this correct?

Comment: Indeed!  Also, in general, the number of basis vectors will be exactly the number of rows of zeros that appear in the reduced row echelon form.  As discussed in alex.jordan's answer, the basis vectors will be nonzero.